# Connecting SSRS to Oracle datasourse

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper, ssrs-2012

I have oracle database named CRMS and using SQL developer to run queries.
I need to make reports using CRMS oracle as my datasourse.

I am using SSRS 13.0
Visual studio 14.0
MS .NET version 4.7
SQL developer 4.1.5

Using Microsoft OLE DB provider for Oracle 
[image]

not sure how to connect to Oracle database. please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need Oracle Client Components installed on your local machine (where you have SSRS installed) inorder to use the Connection Provider for an Oracle Database.

You might want to take a look at the link below:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

Comment: yea I guess that's what I need, Thanks mate

Comment: I’m glad it did work out. @Addy Mark this as the answer if it helped.